# How can I obtain private key from Azure Blockchain Service?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-blockchain-service

I am not sure how I can obtain private key from Azure Blockchain Service.

I would like to use Etherium connector on Logic App. Without private key, the flow fails.

Error message is as below;
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "No private key was found in the connection object\r\nclientRequestId: f85XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXbfea",
  "source": "blockchainethereum-je.azconn-je.p.azurewebsites.net"
}

Please tell me where can I find out these informations, "Ethereum RPC Endpoint", "Private Key", "Account Address" and "Account Password".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [connection description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/blockchainethereum/#creating-the-connection-object), you could find it supports two variations of transaction signing: **Private Key** and **On-node signing**.

And about how to get the keys details, yo could refer to this tutorial:[Configure Azure Blockchain Service transaction nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/service/configure-transaction-nodes). Go to your `Transaction nodes` under your `Azure Blockchain Service`, click the node you want to use, you will get the details.

[image]