# Where to find the private key of a member in azure blockchain service?

Tags: azure, blockchain, azure-logic-apps, azure-blockchain-service

I am trying to create a logic app on azure with ethereum connector, where I am being asked to provide a private key for my ethereum member. I can find the public key in the transaction nodes section of the Azure portal, but where can I find the private key?
Is private key the same as access code?

This question asks the same problem, but the answer provided does not solve the problem: [How can I obtain private key from Azure Blockchain Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56703013/how-can-i-obtain-private-key-from-azure-blockchain-service)

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we can not find the private key in "Azure Blockchain Service" on Azure portal. You may refer to this page to know how to get the private key: https://medium.com/@stef.heyenrath/calling-ethereum-smart-contracts-in-azure-logic-apps-452d6c1156fd

Comment: This is not using Azure Blockchain Service.
If my ethereum account is built on the azure blockchain service, there is no way to find out the private key?
There should be, as azure itself is asking for the private key while creating logic app.

Answer (score 0):

As per the article, the method used to get the PK is via MetaMask and works. If you connect to your Azure Blockchain Service via an RPC connection will allow you to get the private key as per described in the article. This key you'll get will work in your LogicApps connection.